# How does the airline decide how many meals to load aboard a flight?

Tags: passenger

I've researched a bit, and found that entire load of meals may be discarded if a flight is delayed. I've also seen some posts that say first/business class meals are stocked at 110% of capacity. Additionally, some posts say that meals are based on the actual passenger count, rather than the seat count. I'm curious as to the actual practice for determining how many meals make it aboard a commercial flight.

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually [on-topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. It seems to be a question of company policy rather than aviation, which would seem to make it off topic. It may possibly be on topic on [travel.se].

Comment: There are on Travel.SE 2 specific tag that apply to your question when put together [(namely air-travel and food-and-drink)](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-and-drink+air-travel). Your question is a quite good question to be asked there.

Comment: Although to answer the question, they perform some statistical analysis: ie the airline records how many of each meal are used/requested and slowly balance the numbers until you have just enough of each. The 110% stock is due to wanting to ensure that your (profitable!) business class passengers don't go away disappointed, and always have the choice. Economy class tends to carry a few extra of each, but will sometimes run out as they don't carry as large a buffer